# Go Down In History

Tags: usage, idioms

I have a question about the usage of "*go down in history*":

> His heroics will ***go down in history*** as ....
>   His heroics will ***go down in history***.

Does "*go down in history*" have be followed by some sort of "*as....*" clause?  Is sentence 2 poor usage of "*go down in history*"?

Comment: = He will become legendary.  Either way, with/without 'as' is idiomatic.

Comment: _and they shouted out with glee, "Rudolph the red-nosed reindeer, you'll go down in history!"_

Answer (score 1):

The "as" clause is not necessary unless you want to specify WHY he will go down in history.
For example:
His heroics will go down in history. (his heroics will be remembered)
His heroics will go down in history because he won the war. (his heroics will be remembered BECAUSE he won the war, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

*go down in history* is an idiomatic expression, so any clause can be used after it. I found  some examples of using it with the "as-clause" in the BNC (British National Corpus), so, it is correct and completely acceptable:

> Or **shall I go down in history as** the High Queen who lost Tara for
>   always?
>
> She **could go down in history as** the leader who pulled us back from the
>   brink.

Actually, I found out that it is more often to use the expression with "as-clause" than without it, since *go down in history as" is very often used to say how that person went down in history.

The examples of the usage without "as-clause" are the following:

> It was a name that would **go down in history**.
>
> She **has gone down in history** with this quote when she spotted.